# make serialport variable as global to be accessed in a thread

Tags: c#

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Threading;
using System.Data.SQLite;
namespace Datalogging
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public class ThreadExample
    {
        public static void ThreadJob()
        {
            string dBConnectionString = @"Data Source = C:\Users\johnmark\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\SerialTrial\SerialTrial\bin\Debug\employee.sqlite;";
            SQLiteConnection sqliteCon = new SQLiteConnection(dBConnectionString);
            //open connection to database
            try
            {
                sqliteCon.Open();
                SQLiteCommand createCommand = new SQLiteCommand("Select empID from EmployeeList", sqliteCon);
                SQLiteDataReader reader;
                reader = createCommand.ExecuteReader();
                //richtextbox2.Document.Blocks.Clear();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    string Text = (String.Format("{0}", Object.Equals(definition.buffering, reader.GetValue(0))));
                    if (Convert.ToBoolean(Text))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(Text);

                    }
                }
                sqliteCon.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {

        //string received_data;
        //Thread readThread = new Thread(Read);
        FlowDocument mcFlowDoc = new FlowDocument();
        Paragraph para = new Paragraph();
        SerialPort serial = new SerialPort();

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            combobox1.Items.Insert(0, "Select Port");
            combobox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
            string[] ports = null;
            ports = SerialPort.GetPortNames();
            // Display each port name to the console. 
            int c = ports.Count();
            for (int i = 1; i <= c; i++)
            {
                if (!combobox1.Items.Contains(ports[i - 1]))
                {
                    combobox1.Items.Add(ports[i - 1]);
                }
            }
        }
        private void combobox1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {

        }
        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if ((string)button2.Content == "Connect")
                {
                    string myItem = combobox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
                    if (myItem == "Select Port")
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Select Port");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        serial.PortName = myItem;
                        serial.Open();
                        button2.Content = "Disconnect";
                        textbox2.Text = "Serial Port Opened";
                        serial.DataReceived += new System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(port_DataReceived);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    serial.Close();
                    button2.Content = "Connect";
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }


        #region Receiving
        public void port_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            int bytes = serial.BytesToRead;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[bytes];
            serial.Read(buffer, 0, bytes);
            foreach (var item in buffer)
            {
                Console.Write(item.ToString());
            }
            definition.buffering = BitConverter.ToInt64(buffer, 0);
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine(definition.buffering);
            Console.WriteLine();
            Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ThreadExample.ThreadJob));
            thread.Start();
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

Hi. I have this code and I want to put serial.Write() inside this if function:

```
if (Convert.ToBoolean(Text))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(Text);
                    //serial.Write();
                }
```

Can you help me make this serial global so that this error will not exist: The name 'serial' does not exist in the current context?

Comment: It isn't clear what your trying to do here, just an FYI - you cannot write to the serial port from multiple threads at the same time without protecting the read/write with a mutex.

Comment: yeah. my question is how can I call the serial without any error? Since I need to send a character to the serial port whenever the code enters in that if function

Comment: Simple answer (likely wrong): Move `SerialPort serial = new SerialPort();` to `public` `static` class scope.  What does all the SQLite etc have to do with a basic serial port test?

Comment: another problem will arise: an object reference is required for the nonstatic field in threading

Comment: @user3356289 Part of that: **an object reference is required for the nonstatic field** sounds like a valid error.  Combining the rest: **in threading** makes no sense.  Thread or no thread has nothing to do with whether a field is static or not at compile time.  You either got the wrong field, or didn't make enough of the fields you're trying to use `static`.  (Note: This will not solve any of your logic errors)

Comment: Why bother writing to the sql on a separate thread at all? What exactly are you trying to accomplish here?

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is through adding a method to your `MainWindow` class that calls that method, and passing the window instance to your `ThreadJob`.

ie.
Modify `ThreadJob` to accept the instance as a parameter:

```
public static void ThreadJob(MainWindow mainWindow)
```

Place this in `MainWindow` somewhere:

```
public void WriteSerial(string text)
{
    serial.Write(text);
}
```

Modify your `Thread` creation to pass the current window instance:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ThreadExample.ThreadJob(this)));
```

Now after `Console.WriteLine(text)` you should be able to write:

```
mainWindow.SerialWrite(text);
```

I haven't tested this solution, so it may need some cleaning up. It's probably not the best way to do it, as `serial` is part of your window instance (you could separate them).

Comment: Putting a `WriteSerial()` method in definitely seems cleaner, but passing the main window class down to a worker seems messy.  Probably it would all be a whole lot better to move all the interesting bits to the worker `ThreadExample` and let MainWindow call into it (possibly with callbacks) as needed.  There could be an internal worker thread in `ThreadExample` if needed...

Comment: As I previously mentioned, you cannot read and write to a serial port from multiple threads. It's like Ghostbusters - Don't cross the streams. Something like this might satisfy the compiler, but you'll introduce worse, more subtle problems.

Comment: @ebyrob: I agree, I would write it something like you described.

Comment: @asawyer: Agreed, I'm not sure of the purpose of threads here.

Comment: sorry I am a newbie and want to try something different.

Back to the question, I tried putting the thread in my main window and it works fine. After putting serial.Write(), the error will appear.

Comment: @user3356289 "the error will appear"?  What's the error message?  What's the line of code?  (Is it compile-time or run-time?)  Without those details, no one will helping you be.

Comment: Error 2 'Datalogging.MainWindow' does not contain a definition for 'SerialWrite' and no extension method 'SerialWrite' accepting a first argument of type 'Datalogging.MainWindow' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\Users\\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Datalogging\Datalogging\MainWindow.xaml.cs 49 36 Datalogging

Comment: Error 4 Method name expected C:\Users\\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Datalogging\Datalogging\MainWindow.xaml.cs 159 56 Datalogging

Comment: You have to put the `SerialWrite` method in your `MainWindow` class somewhere as I described.

Comment: @iaskyou I notice a discrepancy between `SerialWrite()` and `WriteSerial()`.  You'll likely need to make both the call and the definition the same.  A method must exist (with the correctly matching name) before you can call it.  That's what the compiler is telling you.